# Canadian Winter Cycling Apparel

Tags: clothes, winter

I'm planning in braving the harsh Canadian winter for my daily work commutes via bike. I currently have
[this](https://www.google.com/search?q=MEC+cycling+jacket+vest+supermicroft+men)
nylon jacket, I was wondering if this would be adequate protection? Possibly with an additional layer or two underneath.

Also how would drywick cycling pants fair? Is breathability a bad thing in winter temperatures?

Comment: What part of Canada? Windsor/Vancouver is quite different from Edmonton/Winnipeg.

Comment: Winnipeg city :)

Comment: You're a brave soul.  I'm in Ottawa and don't have the guts to go all winter.  Once the snow comes, I stop.

Comment: Bit late to the party, but  the below -15 °C part of  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/65579/7450 is Winnipeg experience. In terms of clothes, I used layers that were combinations of  long johns, fleece or fleece + waterproof fabric pants, "normal" outdoor pants (IIRC I never used my padded pants for biking, but I used them for winter camping). Thermo under shirt, shirt, fleece, jacket. Mitts that are sufficiently large to be worn over gloves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wear
[MEC Roubaix Tights](https://www.google.com/search?q=MEC+roubaix+tights)
down to about -15 and they work quite well.  The fronts and backs are different material, so they block the wind, while still allowing your legs to dissipate some of the heat.  They aren't so great in the wet, because the backs aren't waterproof, but once the temperature drops below zero, that usually doesn't matter. Although if you have fenders, you might not have to worry at all.

That jacket looks good. You probably want to wear another layer or 2 or 3 underneath. I find that it's all about using lots of layers.  Lots of thin layers can keep you warm, while still allowing for a lot of mobility.

Comment: Hard breathing frigid air is the hard part