# Keeping face warm in the winter

Tags: winter

I regularly use a hat under my helmet and a neck warmer.  This keeps me relatively warm in the winter but leaves a bit to be desired.  What are the best options to keep your face warm?

Some people in NYC particularly those riding electric devices wear full face motor cycle style helmets.  I’ve never tried that but it must keep you warm...

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/50782/19705

Comment: I'm using a ski helmet for winter riding - no need for a hat. But when it's really cold (last winter was like -20C) you have to cover your nape - this adds a lot for feeling warm

Comment: Not sure I should post this as an answer, but it does help: **grow a beard**!

Comment: Could you perhaps add what temperatures you are expecting?

Comment: Another solution is to add a visor, either using a cap/casket or wear a helmet with a visor.  Upside, keeps rain out of eyes.  Downside, tends to limit airflow and you sweat more.

Comment: Those riding electric bikes tend to be working less-hard than conventional cyclists.  So they're not sweating as much, and have less heat.  As a talented local rider once said "you're cold?  Ride harder !  Go put on a hill! "

Answer (score 6):

A trick that I found is used by NFL players to keep their face warm :
"A jar of **Vaseline** is an old trick from veteran players to block out the wind"
source: https://www.espn.com/nfl/story/_/id/14525394/seven-ways-nfl-players-stay-warm-frigid-conditions-nfl

[image]
BONUS: If you get too hot with the vaseline on you can use the excess to lubricate your drivetrain.

I think some skiing/snowboard goggles with a clear lense will also help in keeping your face warm.
Something like this:
https://mx-deals.nl/oakley-crossbril-o-frame-jet-black-clear-lens.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAluLvBRASEiwAAbX3GU82TCnNSiATDbKyg5txyfgQ22RLn0RFJsY-fwpcHCIu53Mn8MTdwxoCEVkQAvD_BwE

[image]

A balaclava looks like it would keep you warm,

you might draw unwanted attention though.

### [image: https://s.s-bol.com/imgbase0/imagebase3/large/FC/4/7/0/7/9200000022417074.jpg]

**This might be a more subtle but similar alternative:** 
[image]

There are even versions of balaclavas which have heating elements inside:

https://www.thewarmingstore.com/heated-balaclava.html
[image]

A full face helmet will definitely also help in keeping you warm, but it's not the most practical solution. I've done a quick search regarding heated motorcycle helmets and could not find much so I assume it will not be needed even in cold conditions.
One comment I found on a forum thread regarding heated motorcycle helmets (to illustrate their effectiveness at keeping your head warm): "Are you serious? Why would you actually need that? A helmet acts like a thermos for your head because of the EPS liner. Keeps you warm in the winter and cool in the summer."
source: https://advrider.com/f/threads/heated-cooled-helmet.639790/

There are heated face shields for full face helmets but I believe their main purpose is to prevent frosting/condensation on the face shield itself, not so much to keep your head warm. They look like this:

[image]

Comment: just remember to take off the balaclava before entering your local bank branch...

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica Reminds me of an episode of a kids' TV show where a character gets a motorcycle helmet stuck on their head and can't see, and goes to a bank when he meant to go to a restaurant, and robs it by accident

Comment: I've used a combination of lower face cover (like a balaclava), a hat, and a set of snow goggles, that combined with Bar Mitts to keep my hands warm yet mobile made riding in -10*F not a problem!

Answer (score 6):

A full-head balaclava that covers the lower face does a good job, but these can be too warm once you get going. I have one that has a separate lower face panel that can be pulled up or down as needed.

There are neck buffs that can be pulled up over the face. Used with a under-helmet hat they provide more adjustability.

There are also face makes made out of a stiffer material with vent holes for breathing  that prevent glasses or goggle from fogging up.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like having my nose or mouth covered when riding. When it's down around freezing, I wear a neck buff pulled up just under my mouth and over my ears, although I could pull it up to cover my mouth if I wanted.

Comment: Neck buffs are awesome for a quick filter too - Riding along and there's smoke from a fire or burnoff, or a dirty truck/bus, or even a dust cloud from any source, you can quickly lift the edge over your mouth/nose.   Don't even have to slow down letalone stop the bike.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a [ColdAvenger](https://coldavenger.com/products/coldavenger-pro-softshell) a long time ago for bicycling to work in around-freezing temperatures and found it worked very well, but reviews online seem to be mixed. See picture below:
[image: ColdAvenger]